# Open activity automatically when receiving fcm notification

Tags: java, android

I am developing a video call app, I want to open an activity automatically when receiving the fcm notification that allows me to send the request to open the activity to answer or not to the video call, all this works perfectly when my application is in the foreground, but it does not work when my application is in the background or closed, Just like whatsApp does, it doesn't matter if the app is in the foreground or background or disabled, calls are always received. THANK YOU!

`

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { //este metodo me servira para recibir los datos que se envien en la N.
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        if (title != null) {
            if (title.equals("LLAMADA")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IncomingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("username", remoteMessage.getData().get("username"));
                intent.putExtra("image", remoteMessage.getData().get("image"));
                intent.putExtra("inviterToken", remoteMessage.getData().get("inviterToken"));
                intent.putExtra("country", remoteMessage.getData().get("country"));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {

                Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
                String body = data.get("body"); //capturamos el cuerpo del mensaje
                String idNotification = data.get("idNotification");

                if (!ifChatActivityInForeground(getBaseContext(), IGNORED_ACTIVITY_NAME)) { // si ChatActivity no esta en primer plano que se muestre la notificacion
                    if (title.equals("MENSAJE")) {
                        getImageReceiver(data);
                    } else {
                        showNotification(title, body, idNotification);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`

I try to put an intent to go to the activity that allows me to answer or reject the video call

Comment: That is [not an option on modern versions of Android for ordinary developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).

Comment: You're looking for [`setFullScreenIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder?hl=en#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,boolean)) on `NotificationCompat.Builder`.  (cc @CommonsWare)

Comment: There's probably a question somewhere on Stack Overflow describing how to do that. (edit: but if there is, I can't find it; I've just found a bunch of really awful advice that won't work)